# Is there any other benefit from static variables other than implementing Singleton?

Tags: c#, clr

I was wondering, is there any benefit in declaring variables or methods static?

Maybe the performance for an application would increase if those static methods/variables are used very often and are always loaded in memory? And the same would apply for variables.

So well, are there any other uses for variables / methods being declared static other than implementing singleton or keeping a global counter or things like that?

Comment: It depends how loosely you define "singleton".  The simplest definition of "singleton" is "static field".

Comment: It also provides a deterministic/knowable name path, which depending on how you define them, may or may not be part of what a "singleton" is.

Answer (score 4):

Static properties are useful for mathematical constants such as `Math.Pi`.

Static methods are commonly used as factory methods to create objects (which are not necessarily singletons).

Static methods are essential for extension methods.

Private static methods are also frequently used for implementation.

Comment: Constants may not be the best example since they're compiled into the actual values and not really static fields. (If you write `Console.WriteLine(Math.PI);`, what actually gets compiled is `Console.WriteLine(3.14159265358979);` - `System.Math` is never used at runtime).

Comment: @JoeEnos That may be so, but the *mechanism* by which you reference the constants is a static field or property. A constant static property or field can be found by reflection, so it doesn't just disappear because it's constant.

Comment: (I mean static constant fields, not properties of course - there's no such thing as a constant property.)

Comment: You're right. I guess I'm just thinking from the point of view of the calling code (in a different assembly) - from that perspective, it's not accessing a static field at runtime, but rather an actual value in its own assembly's IL.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, singleton is widely regarded as an anti-pattern, since it by definition breaks encapsulation, since an object must know it is globally unique. So your question is already broken.

Secondly, it depends on what you mean by "singleton," since any static field is a singleton with respect to the program scope.

Thirdly, some examples include:

- static methods (helpers, factory methods, etc.)
- constants
- Exceptions to the statement "singleton is an anti-pattern," like threadpools, which generally should be coupled to program scope

Answer (score 0):

In general, `static` is used to share things among all instances of the class (and optionally its subclasses). It does not have to be a state, as in a "singleton" or "shared counter" examples. It does not need to be "global" either. In fact, sharing state is less useful than sharing code, and is sometimes regarded as "code smell".

Sharing code logic, on the other hand, is considered good, because it helps you increase code reuse.

- When you need to share code among all instances, say, a common implementation detail of some algorithm, you use a `static` method or an extension method, which must also be `static`.
- Binary operators are defined with a `static` modifier, because they do not take an instance implicitly.
- [Thread-local](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread-local_storage) variables need to be declared `static`.

Answer (score 0):

I think that statics are there to support procedural constructs since everything doesn't neatly slot into OO.

Static methods being the pure functions.
Static variables being commonly used for shared : constants, counters / registers.

Singletons have nothing to do with statics imho, it's just that almost any singleton implementation works with a shared variable (which is commonly static).

Plenty of other OO constructs / patterns can me made with procedure oriented (static) internals.